# Cyberpunk PortProton won't start

Tags: arch-linux, wine, steam

I usually run all games through PortProton and previously ran Cyberpunk and it worked on Ubuntu and later on Arch linux. But then I broke the system and I'm good at it. After reinstalling the game refuses to start. If you press "DEBUG" instead of launching, the last line will have an error:

```
wine: Unhandled exception 0x80000003 in thread c4 at address 0000000142BAD7BB (thread 00c4), starting debugger...
```

I googled it but I can't find the cause of my problem. The system itself was installed from the same flash drive without changing anything, in fact all that was updated was the linux kernel from version 5.17 which I had before the latest 5.18.3. Maybe some drivers, but I don't think that's the reason. The other games like "Resident Evil 8", "Subnautica" or "Age of Empires 4" work fine as before. I have the games on a separate ntfs partition.

Details about the system and stuff:
`5.18.3-arch1-1`
`KDE Plasma 5.24.5`
`X11`
`Driver : nvidia-515.48.07-9`
`GPU: RTX3050 8gb`

Debug log:

```
PortWINE version:
PortProton-1.0
------------------------------------------------------------
Scripts version:
2117
-----------------------------------------------------------
RUNTIME is enabled
----------------------------------------------------------
Debug for programm:
/run/media/Disk_D/GOG Games/Cyberpunk 2077/bin/x64/Cyberpunk2077.exe
---------------------------------------------------------
GLIBC version:
2.35
--------------------------------------------------------
PW_VULKAN_USE=1
--------------------------------------------
Version WINE in the Port:
PW_WINE_USE=PROTON_GE_7-20
PROTON_GE_7-20
------------------------------------------------------
Date and time of start debug for PortProton:
Вт 14 июн 2022 02:38:21 EEST
-----------------------------------------------------
The installation path of the PortProton:
/home/daniilskli/.local/share/PortWINE/PortProton
----------------------------------------------------
Operating system
ОС: Arch Linux
--------------------------------------------------
Desktop environment:
Desktop session: plasma
Current desktop: KDE
Session type: x11
Kernel
5.18.3-arch1-1
-------------------------------------------------
CPU
model name  : AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core Processor
------------------------------------------------
RAM
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15908        6616        4590         287        4701        8631
Swap:              0           0           0
-----------------------------------------------
Graphic cards and drivers:
lspci -k | grep -EA3 VGA|3D|Display:
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 [Geforce RTX 3050] (rev a1) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 887c Kernel driver in use: nvidia Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 8192 MB
    Total available memory: 8192 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 7415 MB
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.48.07
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.48.07
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 515.48.07
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
 
inxi -G:
12Graphics:  12Device-1 NVIDIA GA106 [Geforce RTX 3050] 12driver nvidia 12v 515.48.07 
           12Display x11 12server X.Org 21.1.3 12driver 12loaded nvidia 12unloaded modesetting,vesa 
           12resolution 1920x1080 
           12OpenGL 12renderer NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050/PCIe/SSE2 12v 4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.48.07 
----------------------------------------------
Vulkan info device name:
    deviceName     = NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050
Vulkan cube test passed successfully
-------------------------------------------
D3D_EXTRAS - disabled
------------------------------------------
winetricks.log:
mfc42
w_workaround_wine_bug-50894
vcrun2019
physx
remove_mono
-----------------------------------------
Use /run/media/Disk_D/GOG Games/Cyberpunk 2077/bin/x64/Cyberpunk2077.exe.ppdb db file:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Author: xuser
#Cyberpunk2077.exe 
#Rating=1-5
export PW_VULKAN_USE="1"
export WINEDLLOVERRIDES="Crash*,REDEngineErrorReporter.exe="
export PW_DLL_INSTALL=""
export PW_NO_FSYNC="1"
export PW_NO_ESYNC="1"
export PW_VULKAN_NO_ASYNC="0"
export PW_USE_TERMINAL="0"
export PW_OLD_GL_STRING="0"
export PW_USE_NVAPI_AND_DLSS="0"
export PW_HIDE_NVIDIA_GPU="0"
export PW_FORCE_USE_VSYNC="0"
export PW_WINEDBG_DISABLE="1"
export PW_USE_GAMEMODE="1"
export PW_FORCE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE="0"
export PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=40                    # Fix crackling audio in games
export LAUNCH_PARAMETERS="--launcher-skip"
export PW_GUI_DISABLED_CS="0"
export VKD3D_CONFIG=force_bindless_texel_buffer,multi_queue
export PW_WINDOWS_VER="10"
export PW_VIRTUAL_DESKTOP="0"
export PW_HEAP_DELAY_FREE="0"
#add_in_start_portwine () { "${pw_runtime}" "$WINESERVER" -w }
export PW_WINE_USE="PROTON_GE_7-20"
export PW_PREFIX_NAME="DEFAULT"
export PW_MANGOHUD="0"
export PW_MANGOHUD_USER_CONF="0"
export ENABLE_VKBASALT="0"
export PW_USE_DXR10="0"
export PW_USE_DXR11="0"
export PW_WINE_ALLOW_XIM="0"
export PW_USE_GSTREAMER="1"
export PW_DX12_DISABLE="0"
export PW_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD="0"
export PW_D3D_EXTRAS_DISABLE="0"
export PW_FIX_VIDEO_IN_GAME="0"
export PW_USE_AMDVLK_DRIVER="0"
export PW_USE_SHADER_CACHE="1"
export MANGOHUD_CONFIG="cpu_stats,cpu_temp,cpu_mhz,cpu_color=2e97cb,cpu_text=CPU,gpu_stats,gpu_temp,gpu_core_clock,gpu_mem_clock,vulkan_driver,gpu_name,gpu_color=2e9762,gpu_text=GPU,vram,vram_color=ad64c1,ram,ram_color=c26693,io_color=a491d3,frame_timing=1,frametime_color=00ff00,time,arch,wine,wine_color=eb5b5b,engine_color=eb5b5b,background_alpha=0.2,font_size=24,background_color=020202,text_color=ffffff,toggle_hud=Shift_R+F12,resolution,vkbasalt"
export PW_WINE_FULLSCREEN_FSR="0"
export PW_USE_D3D_EXTRAS="0"
----------------------------------------
# User overides db and var settings...
---------------------------------------
WINEDLLOVERRIDES=d3d12,libvkd3d-proton-utils-3,libvkd3d-shader-1=n;d3d11,d3d10core,d3d9,dxgi,dxvk_config=n;steam_api,steam_api64,steamclient,steamclient64=n;lsteamclient,winemenubuilder.exe=;beclient,beclient_x64=b,n;nvapi,nvapi64,nvml,nvcuda=;Crash*,REDEngineErrorReporter.exe=
------------------------------------
Log WINE:
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: dlopen failed - libgamemode.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
wineserver: using server-side synchronization.
wine: RLIMIT_NICE is <= 20, unable to use setpriority safely
wine: Unhandled exception 0x80000003 in thread c4 at address 0000000142BAD7BB (thread 00c4), starting debugger...
```

*Sorry if there are any mistakes, translated through DeepL.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the ntfs file system. I didn't go into details, but by transferring to a partition with a system that is in ext4 - everything worked.

Comment: FYI some windows game developers are really careless when it comes to case-sensitivity of files, causing occasional weird and seemingly random "file not found" type errors on a case-sensitive filesystem.  If possible, I recommend using a dedicated filesystem that supports case-insensitive filenames for your windows games.  e.g. ext4 with the `casefold` feature, or a case-insensitive zfs dataset.  I have all my windows steam games on zfs dataset with the `casesensitivity=insensitive` property for exactly this reason.

Comment: @cas Well, I just need that this section was also available from under windows for it as well as games programs and other information.

Comment: What? I don't understand what you're saying there. BTW, in case it wasn't obvious, I wasn't disagreeing with you (I upvoted your answer because you solved it yourself AND posted it), I was just pointing out another potential problem you may see with some windows games. e.g. if a dev sometimes writes `/path/to/settings.cfg` in their code and sometimes `/path/to/Settings.CFG` and/or `/Path/To/Settings.cfg`, they are all the **same file** on a case-insensitive fs like FAT or NTFS but are **different files** on a case-sensitive fs (the default on most unix & linux systems) like ext2/3/4 or xfs.